# Opening a light fixture that has plastic clips

Tags: light-fixture

[image: light fixture plastic clips]

Hi, my bathroom light is out and I can't get this fixture open. It has three plastic clips that don't seem to want to let go of the glass. Also seem to be permanently attached to the fixture - I can't budge them sideways or away from the glass other than to bend them slightly but they seem very stiff. Any ideas?

Purchased in Home Depot in Mexico, but I see IKEA recalled a similarly clipped fixture because the clips may break and drop the glass.

Answer (score 1):

One of those clips should be spring loaded and can be pulled out to release the glass. Try again to pull each one of them straight out.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Light fitting installation and removal instructions]

The instructions are to bend the plastic clips and this can result in injury or breaking of the glass, so be very careful.

As stated in the question, IKEA recalled the same design for this safety reason.

[image]